# How do I resize images in Lightbox2?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I'm using http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. I have image thumbnails and on clicking them they open in lightbox - obviously.

The issue I have is that when some of those images are 1800x1200, lightbox covers the whole webpage.

How can I edit to ensure that the images are a maximum height of let's say 400px and width is in proportion? I can't simply upload the images in lower dimensions as they are user uploaded images, so I need to do this script/server side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `max-width` and `max-height` CSS properties on both the images and the lightbox:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rdfAV/1/

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.lb-outerContainer, .lb-dataContainer {
    max-width: 420px;
    width: auto!important;
    height: auto!important;
}​
```

This method appears to be compatible with all major browsers, a full compatibility list is available here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to it :)

Comment: Prefer lightbox so I can see which element I have to edit but CSS one should be ok. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, thanks! The issue is when I set max-height and max-width to `.lb-image` it is still not looking great. I really appreciate the help! thanks

Comment: @Dave, please see my above answer, i'm deleting my previous comments.

Comment: No problem, there are a few catches though, like the `!important` declarations on the w/h properties...

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following to your CSS:

```
 .lb-image{
      max-width: inherit;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks A Lot .. Really Help Full To My Landing Page

Some Editied Code , Play Wisely

```
img {
max-width: 800px;
max-height: 600px;
}

.lb-outerContainer, .lb-dataContainer {
max-width: 800px;
width: auto!important;
height: auto!important;
}​
```